# Why are the variational parameters not changing in VarQRTE runs for TwoLocal ansatz?

Tags: qiskit, variational-quantum-algorithms

Following the qiskit tutorial on [Variational Time Evolution](https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/tutorials/11_VarQTE.html), I've changed the ansatz for VarQRTE from

```
ansatz = EfficientSU2(hamiltonian.num_qubits, reps=1)
```

to

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import EfficientSU2, TwoLocal    
ansatz = TwoLocal(hamiltonian.num_qubits, 'ry', 'cz', reps=1)
```

Plotting the magnetization, I get

[image: Plot of magnetization against time for SU2(blue) and TwoLocal (Orange) ansatze].

Looking at how the variational parameters change during evolution by

```
for i in range(0, len(evolution_result_TwoLocal.parameter_values)):
    print("parameters", i, evolution_result_TwoLocal.parameter_values[i])
```

I note that the parameters are not changing.

```
parameters 0 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 1 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 2 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 3 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 4 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 5 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 6 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 7 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 8 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 9 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 10 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 11 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 12 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 13 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 14 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 15 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 16 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 17 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 18 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 19 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 20 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 21 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 22 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 23 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 24 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
...
parameters 998 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 999 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 1000 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
parameters 1001 [1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633 1.57079633]
```

Is there an easy resolution?